# How to get Developer tools' height in chrome/firefox/safari?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to calculate the height of developer tools in these browsers?
Seems this will check its open state.

```
function isInspectOpen()
{
   console.profile(); 
   console.profileEnd(); 
   if (console.clear) console.clear();
   return console.profiles.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: that code causes an error in chrome...

Comment: no, since the dev tools can take less space than the downloads strip or any other toolbars, there's no way to tell where the wasted real-estate is being spent. also, dev tools can run a completely different window, so visual detectors can miss.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you could do this:

```
var whatever = $(window);
console.log(whatever.innerHeight());
```

Start with dev tools closed, read the value.

Open dev tools, refresh the page and subtract the latter value from the former to get the height of dev tools.

Comment: window.innerHeight is a standard propery, you don't need jQuery for that, and besides, it's still not enough info since the browser can be resized at will...

Answer (score 0):

you can get **Developer tools height** in browser using

```
window.screen.height-window.innerHeight
```

Comment: It's incorrect, because tab bar and bookmark bar are not included.

Comment: that would also only work if the browser was maximized, which is rarely the case on a mac. you might be interested in (outerHeight-innerHeight) if you want to fine-tune  this approach, since that will tell you how many pixels of "chrome/toolbars" are present.